# Difference between "alternate" and "alternative"

Tags: meaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Alternately” or “alternatively”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35440/alternately-or-alternatively)

What is the difference between *alternate* and *alternative*? For example, I have two versions of the same software and I want to write one of the following:

> Software Name (**alternate** version)
>
> Software Name (**alternative** version)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In British English, an alternative version is one that can be considered as a possible choice, while an alternate one changes places at regular intervals with another version. However, I understand that in American English ‘alternate’ is an alternative to ‘alternative’.

Comment: Americans actually use the word alternative quite often, but more often as a noun than as an adjective. (As in, "Are there any alternatives?" or "The alternative is even worse.")

Answer (score 9):

**Alternate** is closer in meaning to *substitute* or second option. (As a noun it refers to a person only. *"Who's your alternate?"*)

**Alternative** can be another possible choice among many. (It can also mean that the two things are mutually exclusive, like when the first thing doesn't work, you look for the *alternative*).

That said, the terms can sometimes be used interchangeably as the meanings can overlap.

Comment: I know of no basis for this response.