# Can the word ''alternate'' be used to mean ''alternative'' in British English?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I recently noticed people use phrases like ''alternate'' news/facts/sources/etc.

I would say ''alternative'' in those situations.

I had a look online and it seems that ''alternate'' is used to mean ''alternative'' in northern America.

How widespread is this usage of ''alternate'' ?

Comment: This usage is not common at all.  The closest usage that is common would be mainly in sports where an alternate is a player that could substitute for another.

Comment: What do British-based dictionaries (Collins, Lexico, CED ...) say?

Comment: This question has already been covered here... [alternately-or-alternatively](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35440/alternately-or-alternatively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acting on the sensible suggestion proposed by Edwin Ashworth some 30 months ago (in a comment beneath the posted question), I consulted several British dictionaries to see how they define *alternate* as an adjective. Here are the results.

From *The Penguin English Dictionary*, revised edition (1969):

> **alternate** *adj (of two things)* following continuously one after the other; arranged alternately; (*bot[any]*) growing along an axis, first on one side, then on the other

From *The Concise Oxford Dictionary*, sixth edition (1976):

> alternate  ... a. (Of things of two things of two kinds) coming each after one of the other kind (**alternative leaves, angles,** those placed alternatively on the two sides of stem, line) ; alternative

From *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*, new edition (1987):

> **alternate** *adj* **1** (of two things) happening by turns; first one and then the other: *a week of alternate rain and sunshine* **2** one of every two; every second: *He works on alternate days.* **3** {[used only before the noun it describes]} *esp[ecially] Am[erican] E[nglish]* instead of another; alternative: *an alternate plan/suggestion*

From *The Concise Oxford English Dictionary*, revised tenth edition 2002):

> **alternate** ... *adj.* **1** every other (of two things) each following and succeeded by the other in a regular pattern. > *Botany* (of leaves or shoots) placed alternately on the two sides of the stem. **2** *chiefly N[orth] Amer[ican]* another term for **alternative**.

And from [Collins [online] Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/alternate) (current):

> **alternate** ... *adjective* ... **[1]** **Alternate** actions, events, or processes regularly occur after each other. | *They were streaked with alternate bands of color.* **[2]** If something happens on **alternate** days, it happens on one day, then happens on every second day after that. In the same way, something can happen in **alternate** weeks, years, or other periods of time. | *Lesley had agreed to Jim going skiing in alternate years.* **[3]** You use **alternate** to describe a plan, idea, or system which is different from the one already in operation and can be used instead of it. | *His group was forced to turn back and take an alternate route.*

The context in which these British dictionaries acknowledge *alternate* in the sense of "alternative" ranges from not recognizing that the meaning exists at all (*Penguin* 1969) to characterizing the meaning as a chiefly North American phenomenon (*Longmans* 1987 and *Oxford* 2002) to not attaching any region-specific label to the definition (*Oxford* 1976 and *Collins* current).

The upshot of the definitions seems to be that whether use of *alternate* to mean "alternative" is mostly North American or universal in English, it is not exclusively North American—and this in turn suggests that there is at least some level of use of *alternate* in this sense in the UK.

Comment: Yeah, the British sense usually seems to imply swapping between the two, while the American allows a permanent substitution. But I don't see it causing much ambiguity or confusion - in situations where someone offers you an alternate or alternative, you should always read the fine print.